# R expand view to see all columns

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to show all columns in RStudio as a viewable table (not console output)? If that doesnt exist, is there a way to show a specific column as a nice table (not console output) without declaring it its own variable?

Comment: say you want columns 30-35: `View(my.dataframe[,30:35]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the columns 30:35

```
View(dataframe[30:35])
```

To see the columns 30 and 35

```
View(dataframe[c(30,35)])
```

Answer (score 0):

For **R - Jupyter Notebook**

To show more columns in R you usually adjust width (up to 10000) or tibble.width (up to Inf) with options. However ***IRKernel***, which is used for working with R in Jupyter notebook, has it's own display method `repr` and out have to set the options manually on it:

```
options(repr.matrix.max.cols=150, repr.matrix.max.rows=200)
```

[Answer source](https://skeptric.com/display-r-jupyter/)